# Perfrom Maven install phase of one child module into another child module using java program

Tags: java, maven, javafx

This is my project structure

```
SampleProject(parent)
 |-- Calculator(packing:jar, child1)
 |-- Gui(packing:jar, child2)
```

In GUI, I want to use classes from the `Calculator` child module. This means, I have to perform `clean install` operation first on `Calculator` and then add `Calculator` project as dependency in `Gui` pom file. This will create `Calculator.jar` in `Maven Dependencies` of `Gui` project. This works perfect, when I do everything manually(by clicking on calculator project and perform `install`).

What I want is following: Since I have `Gui` that has `button`, when I click on that `button`, it should perform `clean install` on `Calculator` project and `jar` will be generated. I am able to do this, when I run on local machine(without releasing final jar of `Gui`). This is my code, to perform maven operation programmatically

```
    @FXML
private void handleProject() {
    project.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
            cli.doMain(new String[] { "clean", "install" }, "../Calculator", System.out, System.out);

        }

    });

}
```

The problem with above approach is that, I am specify path of the `child` module to perform maven operation. Therefore, it works on local machine(without releasing final jar). But when, I release and execute the jar file. It gives me error about `Unable to find Calculator`.

**Is there any way to perform build operation on one child module from another child using java program?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use Maven aggregator plugin

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/prepare-build-env.html